# How do I detect the transparent part of a sprite in unity

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I have a sprite that is partly transparent.

[image]

My aim is to fill the image with some square prefabs.

I have written this code which works fine.

```
while (newY < endVertical)
{
        while (newX < endHorizontal)
        {
                Instantiate(filler, new Vector3(newX, newY, 0), Quaternion.identity);
                newX += fillerWidth + 0.1f;
        }

        newY += fillerHeight + 0.1f;
        newX = startHorizontal;
}
```

The result is

[image]

My goal is however to only draw the white prefabs only on the visible part of the image.
I want my result to be something like this

[image]

To achieve this I have added a little change to check the color at each pixel and only instantiate the prefab if the color is not clear.

```
 var colorSelected = player.GetComponent<SpriteRenderer>().sprite.texture.GetPixel((int) newX, (int) newY);
                if (colorSelected != Color.clear)
                {
                    Instantiate(filler, new Vector3(newX, newY, 0), Quaternion.identity);
                }
```

This, however does not work.

I have also tried this
https://support.unity.com/hc/en-us/articles/206486626-How-can-I-get-pixels-from-unreadable-textures-

Which also fails.

I have figured out if I am able to programmatically know if a particular pixel of my image is transparent or not, then I can figure out the rest.

Someone assist.

Comment: Are your fillers in pixel space? Could you add more details to your question which allows u to reproduce and investigate? In the meantime all I can say is: You are only checking one single pixel ... you would rather need to check if **all** pixels within the given filler rect are fully transparent (`Mathf.Approximately(color.a, 0f)`) .. note that a transparent pixel could be `1, 0, 0, 0` so still red but fully transparent which is not the same as `Color.clear`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Beforehand little disclaimer: This won't be cheap ^^

You will want to get the according pixels at the rect where you are going to spawn a tile and need to check them all if **any** of them is **not** fully transparent.

As you didn't provide much information about your setup I can only try and give solution based on some assumptions:

- Your SpriteRenderer uses the full texture
- The `filler`'s pivot is at the bottom left
- The filler is to be spawned in World Space (in contrary to pixel space of a Screenspace overlay canvas e.g.)
- You don't take rotation into account -> everything happens in the 2D x-y plane

Here is the script I used

```
using System;
using System.Linq;
using UnityEngine;

public class Example : MonoBehaviour
{
    public GameObject filler;

    public Vector2 fillerSize = Vector2.one * 0.5f;
    public Vector2 spacing = Vector2.one * 0.1f;

    public SpriteRenderer spriteRenderer;

    [ContextMenu(nameof(Test))]
    private void Test()
    {
        var sprite = spriteRenderer.sprite;
        var texture = sprite.texture;
        // get the world space dimensions
        var worldBounds = spriteRenderer.bounds;
        // get the pixel space dimensions
        var pixelRect = sprite.rect;

        // Multiply by this factor to convert world space size to pixels
        var fillerSizeFactor = Vector2.one / worldBounds.size * pixelRect.size;
        var fillerSizeInPixels = Vector2Int.RoundToInt(fillerSize * fillerSizeFactor);

        var start = worldBounds.min;
        var end = worldBounds.max;

        // Use proper for loops instead of ugly and error prone while ;)
        for (var worldY = start.y; worldY < end.y; worldY += fillerSize.y + spacing.y)
        {
            // convert the worldY to pixel coordinate
            var pixelY = Mathf.RoundToInt((worldY - worldBounds.center.y + worldBounds.size.y / 2f) * fillerSizeFactor.y);

            // quick safety check if this fits into the texture pixel space
            if (pixelY + fillerSizeInPixels.y >= texture.height)
            {
                continue;
            }

            for (var worldX = start.x; worldX < end.x; worldX += fillerSize.x + spacing.x)
            {
                // convert worldX to pixel coordinate
                var pixelX = Mathf.RoundToInt((worldX - worldBounds.center.x + worldBounds.size.x / 2f) * fillerSizeFactor.x);

                // again the check if this fits into the texture pixel space
                if (pixelX + fillerSizeInPixels.x >= texture.width)
                {
                    continue;
                }

                // Cut out a rectangle from the texture at given pixel coordinates
                var pixels = texture.GetPixels(pixelX, pixelY, fillerSizeInPixels.x, fillerSizeInPixels.y);

                // Using Linq to check if all pixels are transparent
                if (pixels.All(p => Mathf.Approximately(p.a, 0f)))
                {
                    continue;
                }

                // otherwise spawn a filler here
                Instantiate(filler, new Vector3(worldX, worldY, 0), Quaternion.identity, transform);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Result:

[image]